# Plotting non-square array with contour

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a projected 3D plot (contour plot) of a big array with `matplotlib` and it turned out like this:

[image]

I reckon it has something to do with defining the x and y axis. The code I have written for plotting is as following and the data is [here:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3HWMYm2lTkVMjdDcmlfU1ZuVUk/edit?usp=sharing)

​

```
def plotLikelihood(array,m,c):
          xi, yi = np.linspace(m.min(), m.max(), 100), np.linspace(c.min(), c.max(), 100)
          # Interpolate
          rbf = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(m, c,array , kind='linear')
          zi = rbf(xi, yi)
          fig, ax = plt.subplots()
          divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
          im = ax.imshow(zi, vmin=array.min(), vmax=array.max(), origin='lower',
                        extent=[m.min(), m.max(), c.min(),c.max()])
          ax.set_xlabel(r"$Mass$")
          ax.set_ylabel(r"$Concentration$")
          ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
          ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labeltop='on')
          cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
          cbar = fig.colorbar(im,cax=cax, ticks=list(np.linspace(array.max(), array.min(),20)),format='$%.2f$')
          cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)
          plt.savefig('Likelihood2d_MC_NoShapeNoise.pdf', transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
          plt.close()
```

which the inputs of the function are m and c and given as following:

```
     m = np.linspace(0.01, 10, 10000)
     Mass=1e15*m
     Conc = np.linspace(2, 12, 1000)
     likelihood=np.savetxt("Likelihood2d_MC_NoShapeNoise.txt")
     plotLikelihood(likelihood,Mass,Conc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add keyword argument `aspect='auto'` to `imshow` (or do `ax.set_aspect('auto')` afterwards), and your worries are gone...

(Just one humble request: your sample code is almost self-contained and almost working. There are a few imports missing, and the last snippet has some typing mistakes. You could have reproduced the same phenomenon by replacing the 248 MB file by `np.random.random((1000,10000))`. These small things just make it a bit easier to debug.)